# Change Terminal Name to be the Current folder Name

Tags: 12.04, command-line

How to change the title of Terminal to be the Current folder Name?

for example i'm in the folder **test** then the terminal title should be **test** as well.

**Note :**
i don't want the full path  that comes before the folder name(for example `../user/home..`)

Answer (score 1):

This happens anyway, I don't get your point

In `/home`

[image]

Moved to `~/Documents`

[image]

If this does not answer your question, then you need to edit your question for clarity.

Comment: yes, but i don't want the **prefix** that comes before the folder Name(username and the other stuff)

Comment: Then say this in your question, if you don't say that how can anyone know what you want ?

Comment: you're right i was thinking it is abvious as i said change the title of the terminal to the folder name and not the complete full path the current folder